# Create new file and open it in new buffer from within vim

Tags: vim

It's baffling how hard it is to find the magical command that does it.

I'm in vim. All I want to do is create a new file and immediately switch to a new buffer with it. How do I do it?

Answer (score 4):

In the first page of the help (`:help`), see under 'basic editing' the chapter called 'editing.txt' and in that chapter, section 2 'Editing a file'. You can go straight there with `:help edit-a-file`. You will find the following options (among others):

`:edit <your_new_file>` will open a new buffer called 'your_new_file' (or open that file if it already exists). Or even shorter `:e <your_new_file>`.

Or:

`:enew` will create a new buffer for you to edit. (N.B. Then you can use `:saveas <your_new_file>` to save it).

I would recommend going over all the basic editing pages (as well as doing `vimtutor`) if you're new to vim. The sheer number of help pages might seem overwhelming, but getting comfortable with the basics in vim should 'only' take a few weeks of practice. It's all up from there :)